# Search for the meaning 'Even better than the free stash I got off him'

Tags: american-english, cinema

I heard the sentence '*Even better than the free stash I got off him*' in a TV show I watch. I can't grasp the real meaning of it.  Can someone help me here?

[Dexter s02e06 Episode Script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=dexter&episode=s02e06)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even better than the free stash I got off him

Should translate to: This (thing) I obtained was even better than the free (something I didn't pay for) stash (hidden supply) I got off (which could could mean given, stolen, etc) him.

In short, what they have now is better than the free thing they had earlier.